# relationloadstrategy with planetscale and prisma

Tags: mysql, prisma, trpc, planetscale

As far as i've noticed it should be possible to add relationLoadStrategy to Prisma when using planetscale since it works with MySQL. but for some reason i cant make the option to show up.

I figured it's got something to do with Foreign key columns. can anybody tell me how to implement that?

i added this to my schema.prisma:

```
generator client {
    provider        = "prisma-client-js"
    previewFeatures = ["relationJoins"]
}
```

but still don't have the option in my query call